# How to debug the std::function<void()>

Tags: c++

Suppose we have a Task, which is then thrown into the execTask() function for execution.

```
using Task = std::function<void()>;

void execTask(Task task){
    // do sth
    task();
}
```

When we debug, how do we know which Task expression the currently executed task is, because it is a `std::function<void()>`

Comment: I suggest you make your life a bit easier and turn `Task` into a type that can hold some metadata such as a human-friendly name.

Comment: when you step into `task` you'll still be able to see the code that is running

Comment: Or put in a breakpoint in `task()`

Comment: Break on `task()` and then step into it

Comment: @AlanBirtles I try this, it works!  Can we know which task is running by way of logging that can identify the task? Because there are many tasks, I can't step into every task.

Comment: You could just put a logging statement at the start of each task? Or pair your function with a task name?